# writing to file produces an empty file or no file at all

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

my GUI runs on a machine that should be shutdown pressing its button (not via windows screen) in case an error occurs.
the GUI writes an error log into a file, using CStdioFile object, and then pops up an error window announcing user to shutdown machine.
It seems that in some cases, windows is deleting this file, or the file is there but it empty. It looks like file was written to RAM and not to hard disk since I'm shutting it down "brutally".
I tried to add:
int fileLength = myFile.GetLength();
and see fileLength gets the correct length, but even then the file is removed / empty.
tried to add also myFile.Flush(); to force system to write the file on hard disk. Still not working.

What can I do in order to fix this issue?

```
void WriteToErrorLog(CString str, CString traceID)
{
CFileException fileEx;
CFile fileParam;
    
CString strFilePath = _T("C:/Errors/errors.log");
CStdioFile myFile;

if (myFile.Open(strFilePath, CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeNoTruncate | CFile::modeWrite))
{
    myFile.SeekToEnd();
    myFile.WriteString(str);
    myFile.Flush();
    myFile.Close();
    if (myFile.Open(strFilePath,  CFile::modeRead))
    {
        int fileLength=myFile.GetLength();
        myFile.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue was not with modeCreate. As I wrote, the file *was* created correctly, but removed when shutting down the machine.
It seems that I found the issue:
after
myFile.Flush();
I added
FlushFileBuffers(myFile)
which causes all buffered data to be written to a file.
and this forced windows to write file to disk. Seems it works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

From the [`CFile` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfile-class?view=vs-2019) about the `modeCreate` flag:

> Creates a new file if no file exists. If the file already exists, it's overwritten and initially set to zero length.

Then for the `modeNoTruncate` flag:

> Creates a new file if no file exists; otherwise, if the file already exists, it's attached to the `CFile` object.

In short, you should not use the `modeCreate` flag when opening the file.